# INSERTAR DATOS CUANDO MUESTRA PDF

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, insert

este es mi archivo que me imprime un recibo en pdf, pero a la hora de realizar los INSERT INTO en el mismo, no los realiza, me gustaría saber que es lo que estoy haciendo mal, estoy muy desesperado Ayuda por favor, o si tuvieran alguna otra solución se los agradecería muchísimo.

Realiza todo y muestra bien los resultados, como lo mencione anteriormente solo es el detalle que no me inserta lo que le pido.

estoy ocupando las librerias de DOMPDF para realizarlo

lllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll

```html
<?php  
ob_start(); 


$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','*******','*****','*****');

$id = $_GET['id'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM temporal WHERE idtemporal=$id";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);


$query1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT s.idtemporal, u.Nombres, v.Apellidos, s.Mes, s.Ayear, s.Precio 
  FROM temporal s 
  INNER JOIN usuarios u ON s.Usuariost = u.idUsuarios 
  INNER JOIN usuarios v ON s.Usuariost = v.idUsuarios 
  ORDER BY s.idtemporal");
             

              $result1 = mysqli_num_rows($query1);
              if ($result1 > 0) {
        while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)) {
    
             $nombres = $data['Nombres'];
            $apellidos = $data['Apellidos'];
    }     
      }        
    ?>

<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;

  text-align: center;
}

td, th {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
th{
  font-weight: bold;
}
#imagen1{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
#text1{
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#norecibo{
color:#961019;
font-size:14px;
font-weight:bold;
}
#tdfecha{
  text-align: right;
}
#fechaa{
  color:#233f9a;
  font-size:14px;
}
#nombree{
  font-weight: bold; 
  font-size: 14px;
}
#trcol{
  background: #000a60; 
  color: white;
}
#divf{
font-weight: bold;
}
#preciot{
   margin-top: .5%;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 71%;
   text-align: right;
   background: #009aff;
}
#img2{
  position: absolute;
  left: 68%;
}
#firma{
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 12%;
}
</style>
<html>
<body>

  <div>
    <img id="imagen1" src="../img/icon.jpg" width="13%" height="13%" >
  <H5 id="text1">AYUNTAMIENTO DE SAN ANDRES PAYUCA, CUYOACO, PUE. <br>
  COMITE DE AGUA POTABLE.</H5>
</div><br>

<?php  
$sql=mysqli_query($mysqli, "select LAST_INSERT_ID(idRecibo) as last from facturas order by idRecibo desc limit 0,1 ");
  $rw=mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
  $numero=$rw['last']+1;  
?>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Pago de Agua Potable San Andrés Payuca</th>
    <th></th>
      
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><p name="Recibo" id="norecibo">Nº Recibo: <?php echo $numero;?></p></td>

   

    <td id="tdfecha"><p id="fechaa" name="FechaF" >Fecha: <?php date_default_timezone_set('UTC');date_default_timezone_set("America/Mexico_City"); echo date("d/m/Y - H:i:s");?></p></td>
  </tr>

</table>

<div>

<p id="nombree" name="UsuariosF">Nombre: <span id="user"><?php echo $nombres; ?> <?php echo $apellidos; ?></span></p>
 
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr id="trcol">
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Mes</th>
        <th>Año</th>
        <th>Precio</th>
        
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            

   <?php 
   $query2 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT s.idtemporal, u.Nombres, v.Apellidos, s.Mes, s.Ayear, s.Precio 
  FROM temporal s 
  INNER JOIN usuarios u ON s.Usuariost = u.idUsuarios 
  INNER JOIN usuarios v ON s.Usuariost = v.idUsuarios 
  ORDER BY s.idtemporal");
             

              $result2 = mysqli_num_rows($query2);
              if ($result2 > 0) {
           while ($data1 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2)) { ?>
      
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $data1['idtemporal']; ?></td>
        <td id="Mesr"><?php echo $data1['Mes']; ?></td>
        <td id="Ayearr"><?php echo $data1['Ayear']; ?></td>
        <td id="Precior">$<?php echo $data1['Precio']; ?></td>

      </tr>

      <?php
       $fechaa=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
      $detalle=mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO `registropago`(`idRegistroP`,`Usuarios`, `Mesr`, `Ayearr`, `Precior`, `Fecha`,`Recibo`) VALUES (NULL, '$nombres','".$data1['Mes']."','".$data1['Ayear']."','".$data1['Precio']."','$fechaa','$numero');");
     
 } } ?>

    </tbody>
  </table><br>
    <?php  
  $consulta="SELECT SUM(Precio) as TotalPrecios FROM temporal";
$resultado=$mysqli->query($consulta);
$fila=$resultado->fetch_assoc(); //que te devuelve un array asociativo con el nombre del campo

$TotalPrecios=$fila['TotalPrecios']; //Este es el valor que acabas de calcular en la consulta
  
      ?> 

      <div id="divf">
      
      <p id="preciot">PRECIO TOTAL:</p>
      <input type="text" name="PrecioF" value="$<?php echo number_format($TotalPrecios,2);?>" disabled>
   </div>
<?php 
 date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
      $fech=date("Y-m-d");

$fact=mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO facturas (idRecibo, UsuariosF, FechaF,PrecioF) VALUES(NULL,'$nombres','$fech','$TotalPrecios');");
?>
<div>
<img src="pagado.jpg" width="30%" height="30%" id="img2">
<H4 id="firma">_________________________<br>
  FIRMA DE APROBACION</H4>
</div>

</body>
</html>
 <?php
require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html(ob_get_clean());
$dompdf->render();
$pdf = $dompdf->output();
$filename = 'recibo.pdf';
$dompdf->stream($filename, array("Attachment" => 0));

?>
```

Comment: Hola @juan21, Bienvenido! El insert de sql se ejecuta antes incluso de crear el objeto de dompdf, por lo que creo que el problema no debe estar relacionado. ¿Has probado el código comentando lo relacionado con dompdf para descartarlo? Por otro lado, creo que el css supone bastante código extra que podría venir bien quitar para simplificar la pregunta y localizar el problema más fácilmente. ¿Tienes acceso al log del servidor donde se ejecuta el código? ¿la página no devuelve ningún mensaje de error? Un saludo!

Comment: Otro posible hint: No puedo ver la estructura de las tablas afectadas en la base de datos, pero ¿has comprobado si el id de recibo en la tabla de facturas puede ser NULL y el resto de campos tienen el formato adecuado? Algo que puede servirte es imprimir la query en la propia página justo antes de la línea que se ejecuta y lanzarla manualmente en un cliente de base de datos o el propio phpmyadmin -o la consola- para ver qué te devuelve, quizá ahí se muestre el error.